# F# array flatmap

Tags: arrays, f#

I have the following function:

```
let fetchTickerGroup (tickers: string[])  (sqlServer:SQLServerClient) (schema: string) = 
tickers |> Array.map(fun x -> sqlServer.FetchTimeSerie(schema,x))
```

The function takes an array of strings and, through `sqlServer` fetches data which is returned by `sqlServer.FetchTimeSerie` as a `List<b>` where `b` is a custom defined object.
Now, mapping the array means that the function `fetchTickerGroup` returns `List<b>[]`.

I was wondering if it would be possible to `flatMap` the result, rather than just mapping the array values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have no Idea what `Flatmap` is but I think you want to use `*.collect`.

I think the best solution would be something like

```
tickers |> Array.toList |> List.collect (fun x -> sqlServer.FetchTimeSerie(schema,x))
```

you need to convert so that you have only list or array types

Comment: FlatMap, Collect and SelectMany are different names for the same concept

Comment: @Gustavo: thank you, coming from Scala I have used an improper terminology.